# How do I get the title of an entity in hook_entity_presave?

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to get the title of an entity and I can do a dsm of the $entity, but when i do a dsm of $entity->values , nothing shows up.

Comment: See [Entity::label()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Alabel/8.2.x)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the entity is a node, you can do:

`$entity->getTitle();`

Or:

`$entity->get('title')->value;`

Here are a [list of methods for the Entity object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/class/Entity/8.2.x), and for the [Node object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x).

Comment: thanks that works . but how do it test that it's a node?

Comment: I suppose one way is to do `if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) { //code }`

Comment: Thanks, how do i get the workflow status ? i tried to do $entity->getStatus() but that doesnt work.

Comment: You have to use the methods that are available on the class to use. Not sure what else to really tell you beyond that.